# Taxonomy search filters

Tags: filters, search

I have developed an educational courses database of several countries using several taxonomies. Country, institute, study level and some other are taxonomies. If user click on some country, all courses in that country will appear. How the result can be filtered (institute, study level etc) while remaining in the same country.

I would like to put it on archive page so each search could be further filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of `add_query_arg()` and `remove_query_arg()` here. For example http://yourdomain.com/?country=india&institute=pune-university would show results of Pune University in India. You could add `s=symbiosis` to search in the filtered results too. Basically this url would help you out -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg